# Why do_shortcode() works well on public pages, but not on admin pages?

Tags: php, wordpress, admin, shortcode

The same code below returns a text when called on a public page and returns an empty string when called on an admin page.

```
error_log(do_shortcode($sc));
```

Why does it happen? Is there a solution?

```
Shortcode: [amazon-element asin="B01F2JQ8NQ" fields="full-image_clean" container=""]
```

This come from "Amazon Product in a Post Plugin".

Comment: It will be very helpful if you provided the value $sc and the shortcode function. Your question does not provide enough information to really solve the problem.

Comment: You have it now!

Comment: The problem probably is in the implementation of the shortcode 'amazon-element'. Can you provide that also?

Comment: The plugin has thousands of lines. And I believe the same problem happens with any plugin.

Comment: I think the problem is very specific to that shortcode - see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In general do_shortcode() works from admin pages. However, the admin and non-admin environment are quite different. In particular many actions are called in the non-admin environment that are not called in admin environment. It may be that the shortcode 'amazon-element' is somehow dependent on something in the non-admin environment.

Please try another shortcode (e.g. gallery) and you will see that do_shortcode() does work on admin pages at least for some shortcodes.

Incidentally, the shortcode function for 'amazon-element' is called and returning an empty string. If it was not called the argument to do_shortcode would be returned unchanged.

Comment: Sorry, where are you seeing that "the shortcode function for 'amazon-element' is called and returning an empty string"?

Comment: If do_shortcode()  cannot find the shortcode in the global $shortcode_tags it returns its argument unchanged. See its implementation in "...\wp-includes\shortcodes.php".

Comment: You need to go through the code of  'amazon-element' and find out why it is returning an empty string. It may be a bug as shortcodes should be callable from the admin environment usually via AJAX.